# Media print orientation query not working in Chrome

Tags: css, media

I am trying to use the orientation media query during print to change the way my data is displayed. This works in FF and Edge but not Chrome. If I enable emulation in dev tools and select 'print' then my code works. If I try to print though neither the print preview window nor the output change based on orientation.

I have tried locating the style in the html as well as externally.

This is my print.css file:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
   pre {
     font-size: 5px;
   }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) {
   pre {
     font-size: 20px;
   }
}
```

And this is my source file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" type="text/css">
   </head>

   <body>
      <pre>1234567890</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

I would have expected it to display the `<pre>` text in a 20px font size when landscape layout is chosen during print and 5px font size when portrait is chosen. This is the way it works in FF and Edge when either viewing the print preview or actually printing (say to a PDF).